# What's the original form for 'there's' in this sentenece?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, contractions, dummy-pronouns

> Scout, you aren’t old enough to understand some things yet, but
>   **there’s** been some high talk around town to the effect that I shouldn’t do much about defending this man.
>  (Harper Lee, To Kill A Mockingbird)

Is ‘there’s’ the abbreviated form of ‘there is’ or ‘there has’?
If the former is right, for what meaning does the sentence use the passive form?
If the latter is right, is ‘there’ a dummy-adverb (I’ve not heard about it yet) and is its real adverb ‘around town’?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*There's* here represents *There has*.

But the *there* is the ordinary dummy pronoun, and the *has* is not a lexical verb but the auxiliary employed with the past participle of *be* in a present perfect construction:

> There is some high talk ... *present*
>   There has been some high talk ... *present perfect*

One clue that helps you see this is that only verbs which take a direct object ('transitive' verbs) can be cast in the passive. *BE* does not take a direct object but a predicate complement, so a construction with *been* cannot be passive. That rules out *'s* = *is*. It has to be *has*.

Comment: Not to mention which it could have been *"...there's several people been putting it about that I shouldn't do much..."*. In which case you have to ask whether **'s** stands for **is** or **are** (bearing in mind almost no-one says **there is several...**)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Weyull .. There's plenty of folks in Alabama'll say that; though promly not Atticus Finch, leas' not in front of a jury. He's a EDucated man; too educated for his own damn good, some'll say, and not sure I'm not one u'm.

Comment: As [Kosmonaut says here,](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8854/) *It is as if "there's" is becoming a separate lexical item of its own. Linguistically speaking, such a change would certainly be possible.* Anyway, it's "relatively" acceptable to me in speech.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think what both of you say there is exactly right. Moreover, I think it's been around for quite a while; I suspect that the "eye dialect" *they's some*, *they's many*, &c, which starts showing up in US books in the 1840s and is still found quite often, but which I've never actually heard, represents the same thing.